# Referencing a pom jar in child projects

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to centralize all dependencies in a pom in order to remove redundancy. However, when I try to put the `javaee-web-api` dependency in a centralized location it just wont get parsed by my servlet class `EventManager.java`.

My question is: Can you put a dependency with "provided" scope in a parent pom and reference it in the child project?

## parent-proj

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

## child-proj

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.study</groupId>
        <artifactId>poc1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

## EventManager.java (Located in child project)

```
package com.study.webstore.event.processor;

import com.study.webstore.event.AnalyticsModel;
import com.study.webstore.util.GenericUtils;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class EventManager implements Filter {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(EventManager.class);

    //some more code
```

Comment: com.study:poc1 is your parent project?

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare a dependency to an artifact of type pom. You should declare it as your parent pom. Your child pom will inherit from your parent dependencies.

You might take a look at:

- [Maven - Dependency Inheritance - Provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597684/maven-dependency-inheritance-provided)
- http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html